# IF statement in SQL Server trigger with condition

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, triggers

I created a table `student` and I want to create a trigger to stop adding
teacher id after 6 to any student so every 5 student have only 1 teacher.

Teacher id in `student` table is a foreign key so I can repeat in student table
5 times and when I insert 6.. don't agree  I try this code but it does not work

The `student` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    s_id int PRIMARY key,
    s_name varchar(50) ,
    birthday date ,
    t_id int 
)
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_student 
on student
DECLARE
    @count int,
    @s_id int,
    @s_name nvarchar(50),
    @birthdate date,
    @t_id int
Begin
    select @s_id = i.s_id from inserted i;
    select @s_name = i.s_name from inserted i;
    select @birthdate = i.birthday  from inserted i;
    select @t_id = i.t_id from inserted i;

    Select count(*) t_id
    From student
    Where @count = t_id

    If @count < 6 
       Insert into student(s_id, s_name, birthday, t_id)
       values(@s_id, @s_name, @birthdate, @count)

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired'
End
```

Comment: Trigger will be fired once for entire INSERT operation, not ROW by ROW

Comment: so?? .... i try this code but not work will

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo table `Inserted` might contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
select @s_id = i.s_id from inserted i;
select @s_name = i.s_name from inserted i;
select @birthdate = i.birthday  from inserted i;
select @t_id = i.t_id from inserted i;
```

It's undefined - you'll get the values from arbitrary rows in `Inserted`, and you'll **ignore** all other rows.

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge the `Inserted` **WILL** contain multiple rows! You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Inserted` !

Furthermore: the trigger fires **AFTER** the insert has already happened, so your code here:

```
If @count < 6 
   Insert into student(s_id, s_name, birthday, t_id)
   values(@s_id, @s_name, @birthdate, @count)
```

basically inserts the same data **again** - certainly not what you want.

So you need to

- rewrite your trigger to properly deal with **multiple rows** in `Inserted`
- either switch to a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, or change your trigger logic